# A characterization for the kernel of an elliptic operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ a smooth domain and Let $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $-\Delta$. Define the operator
$$
Lu = -\Delta u - \lambda u.
$$
Now I will use the Theorem 3, page 319 from Evans-2010: Consider $\gamma$ a constant such that for each $g \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ there's a unique weak solution $u_g \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$  of the problem
$$
(P)
\begin{cases} L_{\gamma} u := Lu + \gamma u = g, \,\,\Omega \\ \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,u = 0, \partial \Omega
\end{cases}.
$$
In this way, we can define the operator $T: L^{2}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^{2}(\Omega)$, with $T(H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)) \subset L^{2}(\Omega)$ such that $T(g)$ is the weak solution of the problem $(P)$. In other words, if we consider $B_{\gamma}$ the bilinear form associated to the problem $(P)$ we must have the equation
$$
B_{\gamma}(T(g), v) = (g ,v)_{L^{2}}, \forall v \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega).
$$
In adition consider the problem
$$
(\ast)
\begin{cases} L^{\ast} v = 0, \Omega \\ v = 0, \partial \Omega .
\end{cases}
$$
and define
$$
N^\ast = \{v \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) : v \text{ is weak solution of }(\ast) \}.
$$
I would like to know if $N^{\ast} = \ker(L)$ ?

I know how to prove that $v \in N^{\ast}$ if and only if $v - K^{\ast} v = 0$, where $K := \gamma\,T$ is a linear, continous and comapact map. So my question becomes: Is it true that
$$
\ker(L) = \{v \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) : v - K^{\ast} v = 0\} ? \tag1
$$

**What I tried:**  I tried to prove that $K = K^{\ast}$ as follows.
$$
(u , K(v))_{L^{2}} = \gamma (u , T(v))_{L^{2}} = \gamma B_{\gamma}(T(u), T(v))_{L^{2}} = \gamma B_{\gamma}(T(v), T(u))_{L^{2}} = \gamma (v , T(u))_{L^{2}},
$$
which implies,
$$
(u , K(v))_{L^{2}} =  \gamma (v , T(u))_{L^{2}} = (v , K(u))_{L^{2}} = (K(u),v)_{L^{2}}.
$$
However, the conclusion of $K = K^{\ast}$ seems wrong. But if this really works, once we have in a certain way $T =  L^{-1}_{\gamma}$, we would conclude that
\begin{eqnarray}
\{v \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) : v - K^{\ast} v = 0\} &=& \{v \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) : v - K v = 0\} \\
& = & \{v \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) : v = \gamma L_{\gamma}^{-1}(v) \} \\
&=& \{v \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) : v =  L_{\gamma}^{-1}(\gamma v) \}  \\
&=& \{v \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) : L_{\gamma}(v) = \gamma v \} \\
& = & \{v \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) : L(v) + \gamma v = \gamma v \},
\end{eqnarray}
so we would have
$$
\{v \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) : v - K^{\ast} v = 0\} = \ker(L).
$$

What I affirmed in (1) makes any sense? Also, how to prove that precisely that $T =  L^{-1}_{\gamma}$ ?